# How to calculate certain grade when some conditional statement is given using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here i have calculated the average of some PO(program outcomes). After calculating the averages i have to shown the level of attainment or say grade by comparing some conditional statement. The conditions are:

1. If average `>= 80`, the attainment will be `'H'`.
2. If average `>= 60` but `< 80`, the attainment will be `'M'`.
3. If average `>= 40` but `< 60`, the attainment will be `'L'`.

I have calculated the average but cannot find the logic of calculating the attainment level. Some part of code i have done are given bellow.

```html
<script type="text/jscript">
  function calcAvg(input_id, output_id) {
    //Get all elements with 'class="select"'
    var selects = document.getElementsByClassName(input_id);
    //Initialize vars
    var avg = 0;
    var count = 0;
    //Calculate average
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
      if (selects[i].value != "") {
        count++;
        avg += Number(selects[i].value);
        //Alert for debugging purposes
        //alert(selects[i].value+" "+avg);
      }
    }
    avg = avg / count;
    //Output average
    document.getElementById(output_id).value = avg;
  }
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="41" colspan="12" align="center">ATTAINMENT OF PO( PO-CO MAPPING)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="17%" rowspan="2" align="center">NAME OF THE MODULES</td>
    <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">PROGRAME OUTCOMES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO1</td>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">MATHEMATICS</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">SCIENCE</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
    <td height="71" align="center">PO AVERAGES</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg" id="calculation1" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg1" id="calculation2" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">PO ATTAINMENT</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Att1" id="calatt1" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Att2" id="calatt2" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

is how to show automatically the attainment level immediately after calculation of the averages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [if else ladder](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) :

You need to handle the your outcomes would not be greater than 100 & not negative. You have not handled this. Also you need to set attainment for less than 40 currently i hv added -

```js
function calcAvg(input_id, output_id, att_id) {
  //Get all elements with 'class="select"'
  var selects = document.getElementsByClassName(input_id);
  //Initialize vars
  var avg = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var grade = 0;
  //Calculate average
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    if (selects[i].value != "") {
      count++;
      avg += Number(selects[i].value);
      //Alert for debugging purposes
      //alert(selects[i].value+" "+avg);
    }
  }
  avg = avg / count;
  //Output average
  document.getElementById(output_id).value = avg;

  if (avg >= 80)
    grade = 'h';
  else if (avg >= 60)
    grade = 'm';
  else if (avg >= 40)
    grade = 'l'
  else
    grade = '-'

  //Output average
  document.getElementById(att_id).value = grade;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="41" colspan="12" align="center">ATTAINMENT OF PO( PO-CO MAPPING)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="17%" rowspan="2" align="center">NAME OF THE MODULES</td>
    <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">PROGRAME OUTCOMES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO1</td>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">MATHEMATICS</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1','calatt1');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2','calatt2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">SCIENCE</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1','calatt1');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2','calatt2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
    <td height="71" align="center">PO AVERAGES</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg" id="calculation1" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg1" id="calculation2" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">PO ATTAINMENT</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Att1" id="calatt1" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Att2" id="calatt2" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @RobG I have made changes

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use a switch statement, as follows:

```js
 function calcAvg(input_id, output_id,att_id) {
          //Get all elements with 'class="select"'
         var selects = document.getElementsByClassName(input_id);
          //Initialize vars
          var avg = 0;
          var count = 0;
          var grade = 0;
           //Calculate average
           for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
          if (selects[i].value != "") {
          count++;
           avg += Number(selects[i].value);
          //Alert for debugging purposes
           //alert(selects[i].value+" "+avg);
           }
          }
         avg = avg / count;
          //Output average
          document.getElementById(output_id).value = avg;
          
          switch( true ) {
          case avg >= 80: 
               grade ='H';
               break;
          case avg >= 60:
               grade ='M';
               break;
           case avg >= 40:
               grade ='L';
               break;
           default:
               grade = '-';
               break;
          }
          
           //Output average
          document.getElementById(att_id).value = grade;
          }
```

```html
      <table>
          <tr>
         <td height="41" colspan="12" align="center">ATTAINMENT OF PO( PO-CO 
         MAPPING)</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
         <td width="17%" rowspan="2" align="center">NAME OF THE MODULES</td>
          <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">PROGRAME OUTCOMES</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
        <td width="7%" align="center">PO1</td>
        <td width="7%" align="center">PO2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
         <td height="71" align="center">MATHEMATICS</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" 
       onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" 
       onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1','calatt1');" 
       style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" 
       onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" 
       onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2','calatt2');" 
      style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td height="71" align="center">SCIENCE</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" 
      onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" 
      onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1','calatt1');" 
     style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" 
     onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" 
     onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2','calatt2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
     </td></tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
     <td height="71" align="center">PO AVERAGES</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg" id="calculation1" 
      readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg1" id="calculation2" 
      readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td height="71" align="center">PO ATTAINMENT</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Att1" id="calatt1" readonly 
     style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Att2" id="calatt2" readonly 
      style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Note, the switch statement accomplishes the goal with an expression evaluating as true. When that result matches one of its cases evaluating the same way, then an appropriate grade can be assigned. The advantage of the  switch is that it reduces the complexity of the grading logic. See this [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).